# How do get the latest commits from a remote repository?

Tags: git

In our team only person B is allowed to push changes to our remote repository. Other devs like person A create a fork of that remote repository. Person B has to take care of person A's changes ending up in the remote repository.

Let's say that person A made a commit to his forked repo.
Person B then clones person A's repo.
Person A makes some changes in his repo. Person B then wants to pull these changes in his repo that he cloned before from person A. This allows person B to push person A's changes to the remote repo.
It might be that person A has to make some more changes. Person B needs to be able to pull these changes too and push them to the remote repo.

We are unsure how to accomplish this with git. Any tips?

These are the commands person B tries to execute:

```
git clone reponame-from-person-a.git
cd reponame-from-person-a
git checkout branch-from-person-a
git commit --amend --author="Person B <person.b@company.com>"
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin reponame-from-person-b.git
git push --set-upstream origin branch-from-person-a
git push -f
```

Then when person A made some more changes person B tries this:

```
git pull
```

What we expect is that the latest changes from person A are now pulled. Unfortunately this is not the case.

Comment: Sound like regular pull requests from feature branches to the master branch where only person B is allowed to merge. [read this guide for a deeper understanding](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow)

Comment: You don't need to *replace* `origin`; you can have multiple remote repositories.

Comment: `git clone -o person-a reponame-from-person-a.git`, followed by `git remote add person-b reponame-from-person-b.git`. There's nothing special about the name `origin`; it's just the default name for the remote added automatically by `git clone`, and you can override it using the `-o` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `git` is a *distributed* VCS, all of that cloning isn't necessary after everybody's gotten a copy.

For example:

```
Origin:
      master
        |
A---B---C
```

Person A forks and creates `feature` branch:

```
Person A:
  origin/master
        |
A---B---C---D---E
                |
             feature
```

go ahead and let Person A push it to Origin:

```
Origin:
      master
        |
A---B---C---D---E
                |
             feature
```

`feature` will be on the remote server, but the changes are not in `origin/master`, since you've defined that only person B is allowed to realize changes in `master`. The existence of `feature` on the remote server doesn't affect `origin/master` at all.

At this point, person B, who DOES have the authority to incorporate `feature` into `master`, can Fetch to get an updated "copy of everything", after which he can execute the merge by creating the merge-commit F from `master` and `feature`:

```
Person B:
  origin/master
        |
A---B---C-------F
         \     /
          D---E
              |
           feature
```

Note that the changes are still not on `origin/master`. All changes so far are only on Person B's local repo's `master` branch:

```
Person B:
origin/master  master
        |       |
A---B---C-------F
         \     /
          D---E
              |
           feature
```

The changes are *still* not on `origin/master`. (I'm breaking this down step-by-step). Only after Person B Pushes `master` to Origin, will it be updated on Origin, which only Person B is permitted to do:

```
Origin:
              master
                |
A---B---C-------F
         \     /
          D---E
              |
           feature
```

Throughout this whole process, authorship and commitership is being tracked. Anybody that Fetches the repository at this point will see `feature`, written by Person A, has been merged and incorporated into `master` by Person B

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a regular flow which most of the organisations follow. Below step will help you achieve this:

- Person A commits the changes and opens up a Pull Request stating from which branch of forked repo should it merge to which branch of remote repo(Person B's repo)
- Person B reviews the changes and merges it.

Refer [this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-requests) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how your team work but never seen this kind of workflow before. Person B is not supposed to clone person A's repo.
I recommand you to check [this](https://reflectoring.io/github-fork-and-pull/) simple article !

Comment: There's nothing wrong with cloning another person's repo. That is in fact an intended use case -- `git` is a _distributed_ vcs, after all. That being said, if they've already got a copy of the repo, `fetch`ing _would_ be more efficient.

Comment: Totaly agree, just meant that it was not necessary as you clearly explained in your answer, +1 for all the details you gave !